# How to run web application on testing environment

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Can I run or deploy java web application inside selenium, without having to first deploy it in any web container.

So, I want to deploy web app in selenium testing environment. Can it be done ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is for handling your browsers and not for hosting a website.. It's not a webserver software like Tomcat, Apache.

Selenium expects an web URL to launch the application, which means, you need to have a web application up and running either hosted locally or in remote web sever..

Answer (score 0):

You cant deploy application inside Selenium.

What you are expecting is CI/CD pipeline, this you can achieve using any tools like Jenkins/Cruise Control etc. In this you need to maintain a separate environment(where you have to host your application) in which you will be executing your selenium tests, and only if those tests gets passed you can promote that build to other environments like QA/UAT etc.